# How to use sed command to delete lines without backup file?

Tags: linux, file, vim, sed, redhat

I have large file with size of 130GB.

```
# ls -lrth
-rw-------. 1 root root 129G Apr 20 04:25 syslog.log
```

So I need to reduce file size by deleting line which starts with "Nov 2" , So I have given the following command,

```
sed -i '/Nov  2/d' syslog.log
```

So I can't edit file using VIM editor also.

When I trigger SED command , its creating backup file also. But I don't have much space in root. Please try to give alternate solution to delete particular line from this file without increasing space in server.

Comment: How come it is creating a backup file also? What's the name of it? What if you say `sed -i ''`? Are you in Red Hat for sure or in OSX?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not create a real backup file.  `sed` is a *stream* editor.  When applied to a file with option `-i` it will *stream* that file through the `sed` process, write the output to a *new* file (a temporary one), when everything is done, it will rename the new file to the original name.

(There are options to create backup files also, but you didn't give them, so I won't mention that further.)

In your case you have a very large file and don't want to create any copy, however temporary.  For this you need to open the file for reading *and* writing at the same time, then your `sed` process can overwrite the original. After this, you will have to truncate the file at the end of the writing.

To demonstrate how this can be done, we first perform a test case.

Create a test file, containing lots of lines:

```
seq 0 999999 > x
```

Now, lets say we want to remove all lines containing the digit `4`:

```
grep -v 4 1<>x <x
```

This will open the file for reading and writing as STDOUT (1), and for reading as STDIN.  The `grep` command will read all lines and will output only the lines *not* containing a `4` (option `-v`).

This will effectively overwrite the beginning of the original file.

You will not know how long the output is, so after the output the original contents of the file will appear:

```
…
999991
999992
999993
999995
999996
999997
999998
999999
537824
537825
537826
537827
537828
537829
…
```

You can use the Unix tool `truncate` to shorten your file manually afterwards.  In a real scenario you will have trouble finding the right spot for this, so it makes sense to count the number of bytes written (using `wc`):

(Don't forget to recreate the original `x` for this test.)

```
(grep -v 4 <x | tee /dev/stderr 1<>x) |& wc -c
```

This will preform the step above and additionally print out the number of bytes written to the terminal, in this example case the output will be `3653658`.  Now use `truncate`:

```
truncate -s 3653658 x
```

Now you have the result you want.

If you want to do this in a script, i. e. without interaction, you can use this:

```
length=$((grep -v 4 <x | tee /dev/stderr 1<>x) |& wc -c)
truncate -s "$length" x
```

I cannot guarantee that this will work for files >2GB or >4GB on your machine; depending on your operating system (32bit?) and the versions of the installed tools you might run into largefile issues.  I'd perform tests with large files first (>4GB as this is typically a limit for many things) and then cross your fingers and give it a try :)

Some **caveats** you have to keep in mind:

- Of course, nobody is supposed to append log entries to that log file *while* the procedure is running.
- Also, any abort during the running of the process (power failure, signal caught, etc.) will leave the file in an undefined state.  But re-running the command again after such a mishap will in most cases produce the correct output; some lines might be doubled, but not more than a single line should be corrupted then.
- The output *must* be smaller than the input, of course, otherwise the writing will overtake the reading, corrupting the whole result so that lines which should be there will be missing (or truncated at the start).

Comment: Agreed, I can't think of any shell means to do the no-copy trick. I'm having trouble thinking of *anything* that can avoid a partial copy given Unix filesystem semantics.

Comment: @Alfe, Do you have any other way to overcome this issue? Since it is so large file , i couldn't open in VIM editor also.

Comment: Disks are super cheap. Even a 200GB usb thumb drive can be had for under US$50.

Comment: @msw : Thanks for your suggestion , I will try to ask storage team to provide space.

Comment: @Vathinth I found a way to use overwriting for stripping unwanted lines.  See my edit in the answer.

Comment: Alfe, that's a clever hack but I can envision race conditions that would be data corrupting. I would not suggest anyone who cares about data integrity use it.

Comment: @Vathinth I added some part about automating the finding of the size to `truncate` to.

Comment: @msw Please elaborate on the race conditions you fear.  ① Of course, nobody is supposed to append log entries to that log file while the procedure is running.  ② Also, a power failure during the process will definitely leave the file in an undefined state.  ③ The output _must_ be smaller than the input, of course, otherwise the writing will overtake the reading.  Any more issues you can see?

Comment: @Alfe : thanks for the alternate solution , let me try it first in server.

Comment: ++; on two tangential notes: `seq 1000000 > x` is a much faster alternative for creating the test file. To call `truncate` a "shell utility" is a little confusing (it's a CLI not related to the shell per se).

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for the suggestions, I adopted your comments into the answer (I think the term 'Unix tool' is more fitting than 'shell utility').

Comment: @Alfe: Great .... It works and I have reduced the file size from 129GB to 107GB . Thanks for your timely help.....

Comment: Unfortunately grep now reports `grep: input file ‘(standard input)’ is also the output` and refuses to write to the file (assuming I haven't done a mistake). Tested on versions 3.3 and 3.6 -- not sure when this behavior was changed. FYI another use case for this is to edit bindmounted files which simply cannot be replaced (or in any non-writable directory I suppose). Anyone here who might have another solution or alternate tool suggestion to answer this question (short of writing a custom program or reverting to an older version or grep): any hint would be appreciated.